# How to clear Laravel Queue using iron.io

Tags: laravel-4, queue, iron.io

I'm working on TeamSpeak management system based on Laravel 4
the problem is when i restart the script it add the queue again unless i restart the Queue listener

is there a way to clear the old Queue on script startup without the need to restart the queue:listen ??

am using Iron.io service as a queue engine

Thanks in advance

**//EDIT**

Thanks to "thousandsofthem"
it works with Laravel like this:

```
$queue_name = Config::get('queue.connections.iron.queue');
Queue::getIron()->clearQueue($queue_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about touching `$iron_mq->clearQueue($queue_name)` ?

https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php/blob/master/IronMQ.class.php#L235

No idea how Laravel exposes it though

Comment: finally got time to test it works like charm thanks :)